# Quick Probability question involving percentages

Tags: probability

Robots A & B make toys. Robot B makes 75% of toys. When made by B 5% of the toys are faulty. When made by robot A only 10% are faulty. 
Calculate the probability that when a toy is picked at random:

A) is made by robot B and is faulty

B) is not faulty

So far I got

A) 0.05 x 0.75 = 0.0375

B) 0.85 x 0.15 = 0.1275

Is that correct or do I need to do another formula ?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your question.

Comment: If you are satisfied with John's answer, accept it. If you are not satisfied, *add* to your question to explain where you are still confused.

Answer (score 3):

Your part A) result is correct. For part B), a toy is not faulty if it's made by $A$ and not faulty, or made by $B$ and not faulty, so the probability of this occurring is $0.25 \times 0.9 + 0.75 \times 0.95 = 0.9375$ instead.

Note the $0.25$ comes from $100\% - 75\% = 25\%$ of the toys being made by robot $A$, $0.9$ comes from $100\% - 10\% = 90\%$ of the toys made by robot $A$ not being faulty, the $0.75$ comes from robot $B$ making $75\%$ of the toys, and the $0.95$ comes from $100\% - 5\% = 95\%$ of the toys being made by robot $B$ not being faulty.

Comment: @ClaireTMukiibi You're welcome. I've added more details to my answer explaining not only where the $0.25$ and $0.95$ come from, but also the other $2$ numbers as well. I hope it's all clear to you now.

Answer (score 0):

Let the following events called $A,B$ and $F$:

- $A$: The chosen toy is made by Robot A.
- $B$: The chosen toy is made by Robot B.
- $F$: The chosen toy is Faulty.
- $\bar{F}$: The chosen toy is not Faulty.

The answer to your questions:

**A)** 
is made by robot B and is faulty.
$$P[B \cap F] = P[B] P[F|B] = 0.75 \cdot 0.05 = 0.0375$$
So your answer is correct for this case.

**B)** 
is not faulty.

You need to use the [law of total probablity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability), here:
$$P[\bar{F}] = P[\bar{F}|A] P[A] + P[\bar{F}|B] P[B] = 0.25 \cdot 0.9 + 0.95 \cdot 0.75 =  0.9375$$